Call Informatica wf from different Repository
I need to run already existing wf from different repository with different parameters. Is it possible and how?

yes, possible.
Create a command task and set the command as
pmcmd startworkflow -sv IS_XX -d DOM_XX -u MyUser -p MyPassword -f myFolder -paramfile /home/user/wf_xx.txt -wait wf_xx

Couple of imp points -

Parameter file should be in either in local drive or shared drive where the user running informatica should have read access to. And the file path should be correct.
The user which is running this command should able to reach the domain server reach physically (i.e. TCP/IP access is not blocked by a firewall).

it will be difficult to check if the workflow succeeded or failed so i would recommend to have a fail mail on target workflow
